# How to skip an activity's result for another activity than the subsequent activity in a sequential workflow?

Tags: c#, workflow-foundation

I'm with a sequential workflow, say with three activities
1. Get Images
2. Rotate Images
3. Flip Images

Now I want something like this, that for the 3rd activity, the input doesn't come from 2nd activity but from the 1st activity.

means, in 3rd activity, I want the original images to be flipped, den the rotated images to be flipped.

thanks for the help in advance.

Regards

Comment: I'm working with WF4, but everything is going in code behind, so no matters as if WF3 or WF4.

Answer (score 0):

You could place the results of GetImages into a Sequence scoped collection variable, place the results of RotateImages into another Sequence scoped collection variable, then FlipImages could flip both the original images and the rotated images. That sounds to me like it would work...